# Remotebuilderror with visual studio + cordova (error code 65)

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2017, code-signing

I am trying to build (remotebuild) an IOs App with Visual Studio 2017 (Cordova) on Windows 10 but getting a build error: "Build failed with error Error Code 65 for command: xcodebild with args".

When I take a closer look at the build.log file on my Mac it shows me a Code signing error:

Code Signing Error:

```
 [Application] requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile for the "Release" build configuration in the project editor. Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.3'
```

I've already created an provisioning Profile manually via https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/create but how can I include that file in my build configurations, if I am not building the application with Xcode directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to include the details in your build.json file, something like this:

```
"ios": {
  "debug": {
    "packageType": "development",
    "developmentTeam": "YOUR_DEV_TEAM_ID",
    "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
    "provisioningProfile": "PROVISIONING_PROFILE_UUID"
  },
  "release": {
    "developmentTeam": "YOUR_DEV_TEAM_ID",
    "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
    "provisioningProfile": "PROVISIONING_PROFILE_UUID",
    "packageType": "enterprise"
  }
}
```

Check that the app id that you used to create your provisioning profile matches the id that's specified at the top of your config.xml file.

Comment: Thanks but I have already included all your mentioned details in my build.json.

Comment: What versions of cordova/iOS platform are you using? Presumably you've installed the provisioning profile on the Mac?

Comment: I have made an export of my project and built it directly in Xcode. Wasted too much time to build it in VS. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No probs. Don't blame you for going down the Xcode route, a shame it's such a pain in the butt via VS  :-/

Answer (score 0):

Add `--buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"` to your build.json file.